# How to Sync My Windows Server time to user

Tags: windows, sync, windows-server-2012-r2, date-time

We are using a **Windows Server 2012 R2** in our Company, and we have **active directory with 100+ users**. but we are facing a issue, When our user restart their computers, their computers aren't **syncing time and date from server**, I've tried many methods, but not successfully in fixing this issue. If anyone have any idea about it, that would be Highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us what already did? Maybe the port 123 is blocked by clients, firewalls, ... https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings

Comment: We've tried the ways you refer the link. but didn't successful